# iOS reference relationship between subview and superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the iOS documentation, it seems that subview has a strong reference to superview:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *superview
```

The default for property is **strong**.
As we all know, superview has a strong reference to subview, so is there a reference cycle between superview and subview?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a reference cycle. To get rid of a view, you have to call `[theView removeFromSuperview]` which breaks the cycle.

Answer (score -1):

No, the default is `assign`. That's roughly the same as unsafe-unretained.

Comment: The default is now `strong`. It used to be `assign` but Apple changed it a few years ago.

Answer (score -2):

There won't be any reference cycle. When superview is deleted, it will delete all its children first before deleting itself. If you just want to delete current view, you can do it. Superview don't object.